# Difference between web3.eth.personal.getAccounts() with web3.eth.getAccounts()

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, json-rpc, accounts

What are the differences between `web3.eth.personal.getAccounts()` and `web3.eth.getAccounts()`?

## environment

- truffle: v5.1.7
- using `truffle console`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is what RPC method is being called under the hood. From [the docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-personal.html):

> `web3.persal.getAccounts` returns a list of accounts the node controls by using the provider and calling the RPC method `personal_listAccounts.`
>
> The results are the same as `web3.eth.getAccounts()` except that calls the RPC method `eth_accounts`.

Comment: Sorry to ask because this is another question,  so if you knew tell me please. Actually I am now connecting to azure blockchain service(working on quorum protocol), and two methods return totally different addresses. Can you guess why this happens ?